# Problems with SQLNCLI connection string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, adodb

We have fresh installation of SQL Server 2012 on WIN2012 64 bit.
According to ODBC Administrator, SQL Server native Client 11.0 is installed, too.

However, while trying to connect to SQL with "Provider=SQLNCLI..." or "Provider=SQLNCLI11..." or "Provider="SQLNCLI11.0...", we receive an error:

> ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a' Provider cannot be found. It may not
>   be properly installed.

Our webpage is in classic ASP, app.pool enable 32-bit applictions is True, Managed pipeline is Classic.

Interesting, while we try to connect to the same SQL with OLEDB, t.i. "Provider=SQLOLEDB..." everything works just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:
We have SQLNCLI on SQL server only, and NOT on our WEB server, which wants to connect to SQL.
After we installed SQLNCLI on our WEBSERVER, connection succeeded.